# What is the color palette used by igraph?

Tags: igraph

My reproducible example is the following:

```
get.vertex.attribute(g)
$name
 [1] "LV" "Ve" "Ca" "Ai" "BN" "EN" "Or" "So" "SG" "Bo" "AX" "Sa" "To" "Pe" "Da" "He" "VI" "Ke" "Va" "At" "Ac" "Mi"
[23] "Cr" "Le" "Pu" "Re" "Te" "C." "N." "Y." "M." "D." "F." "L." "P." "S." "B." "J." "I." "A." "H." "R." "E." "O."

$color
 [1] 1 1 1 1 1 2 3 1 1 3 1 3 3 3 1 4 3 5 3 1 1 6 2 6 1 3 3 1 1 1 1 3 1 2 3 1 5 1 2 3 3 4 3 6
```

In my case, the following code:

```
library("igraph")
vertices<-data.frame("name" = unique(unlist(relations)))
g = graph.data.frame(relations, directed=F, vertices=vertices)
vertices$group = edge.betweenness.community(g)$membership 
V(g)$color <- vertices$group
plot(g,layout=layout.auto,vertex.size=6,  vertex.label.cex = 0.8)
```

gives this graph:
[image]
where the color 1 seems to be orange, 2 is light blue, etc...
yet

```
palette()
[1] "black"   "red"     "green3"  "blue"    "cyan"    "magenta" "yellow"  "gray"   
>
```

So what is the color palette used by igraph?
I am curious because I would like to use it in another package that only takes names of colors as input and doesn't seem to recognize the V(g)$color vector as a candidate for input (ie outputs only black).

Comment: A small note on "only takes _names_ of colors": the underlying color scheme in R (and consequently in igraph) is the same as in HTML/CSS. This means that instead of, say, `V(g)$color <- "cyan"` you may call `V(g)$color <- "#00FFFF"`. What is generally called "name" is actually an _alias_ (the former), whereas the _real name_ of a color is a string of its hex code (the latter). This is **very** useful as it allows you to first treat colors numerically (in a 32-bit universe!) and only then convert them into a string (even if this color doesn't have an alias).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is `categorical_pal(8)`.

**Full Story**

If you look at the help page `?igraph.plotting` and search on `palette` you will find.

> palette
>
> The color palette to use for vertex color. The default is
>   `categorical_pal`, which is a color-blind friendly categorical palette.
>   See its manual page for details and other palettes.

The help page `?categorical_pal` says:

> This is a color blind friendly palette from
>   http://jfly.iam.u-tokyo.ac.jp/color. It has 8 colors.

We can make a quick demonstration of this.

```
library(igraph)
x = 1:8
y = rep(1,8)
plot(x,y, pch=20, cex=10, col=categorical_pal(8), xlim=c(0.5,8.5))
```

[image]